# Getting this error when trying to implement Chartboost on Swift xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, ads, chartboost

I have this code to add my AppID and App Signature to my AppDelegate.swift file but I get an error on the last line of code. It says: "Cannot invoke startWithAppId with an argument list of type (String, String, Delegate: AppDelegate). What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let kChartboostAppID = "5236547547457856858568"
    let kChartboostAppSignature = "523525225"

    Chartboost.startWithAppId(kChartboostAppID, appSignature: kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the ChartboostDelegate initializer. It works now!